# matplotlib animated subplots in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create an animation within a jupyter notebook. I am using `matplotlib.animation`to do the animation of the plots. I need some help in writing the `run` function from the animation. As I understand the run function should return a list. As a get a run time error when I run the following code.

```
RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.
```

Can someone please help me overcome the difficulty

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def run(it):

    plt.subplot(131)
    plt.title('original')
    plt.imshow(x[:,:,it],cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

    plt.subplot(132)
    plt.title('original 2')
    plt.imshow(y[:,:,it],cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

    plt.subplot(133)
    plt.title('original_3')
    plt.imshow(z[:,:,it],cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])



 ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, frames=np.arange(0,10), 
                        interval=30, blit=True)

 #ani.save('mwe.mp4')
 plt.show()
```